# Methods that use convertPoint:fromLayer implicitly in Xamarin.iOS/MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

Can anybody give me clues as to which methods use `convertPoint:fromLayer` implicitly? Thank you very much in advance.

After the last update of my Xamarin.iOS app I get frequent crash reports from users that all look like the one below (UIButtonContent can be any other (possibly generated) type like UImage, __NSCFType, __NSCFDictionary, OS_voucher, etc.).

`Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[UIButtonContent convertPoint:fromLayer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145c52e0 at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowNSException (IntPtr ns_exception) [0x00000] in :0 at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception (IntPtr exc) [0x00000] in :0 at (wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Runtime:throw_ns_exception (intptr) at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00000] in :0 at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00000]`

The cause of the crashes seems to be a memory management issue in my app (multiple posts found on this type of exception). However, I have trouble pinpointing the error in my app, because the error message points to code - `convertPoint:fromLayer` - I do not explicitly use myself.

Btw the problem seems to be iOS 8 specific. My app supports lower iOS versions, however crashes only occur on devices with iOS 8.

Comment: The symbolicated crash report (you can get it from Xcode) might give you a better idea from where this native exception comes from (e.g. a better/more complete stack trace).

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion. Unfortunately I have not been able to reproduce the crash myself, I only have some crash reports  from users that are limited to the info as seen above, and no clue as to where in the app and with what actions the crash occurs.

Answer (score 0):

That methods would be ConvertPointFromLayer if you are using it from C#.   And it would indicate that you are calling this method on a CALayer that is no longer in memory.

Comment: Thanx for your reply, however I do not call ConvertPointFromLayer explicitly in my code. That's why I assumed it would be called implicitly in other methods, hence the question.